# sed replace text between 2 strings

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm new to `sed` and not been able to get this working despite looking at various examples online.
Basically, I have a text file where I want to use `sed` to replace an unknown string between 2 known strings. I'm using bash on Mac. This is what I have so far

BuildFinish.txt contents:

```
{
"text": "Build: Old Build was successful",
}
```

Bash code:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/("Build: ")\(.*\)(" was successful")/\1 "New Build" \2/g' BuildFinish.txt
```

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: `sed -e 's/\("Build: \)\(.*\)\( was successful"\)/\1 "New Build" \3/g'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `\(` and `\)` to capture groups.  Use `(` and `)` to match literal parentheses.  Not sure what you're trying to do with the double quotes.  Try:

```
$ echo '"text": "Build: Old Build was successful"' |
        sed -e 's/\("Build: \).*\( was successful"\)/\1New Build\2/g'
"text": "Build: New Build was successful"
```